# Is there any way to figure out the count of maximize, minimize, and close buttons According the window style?

Tags: windows

I'm repainting the non-client zone of a window. When I try to do my own drawing of the maximize, minimize, and close buttons , First I should know how many buttons and which buttons need to be drawing. It seemed referring to the window sytle (GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE)).

for example ,
WS_MAXIMIZEBOX: there would be a maximize button.
WS_MINIMIZEBOX: there would be a minimize button.
And It seemed no style bit for window close button(Can someone tell me for sure?).

So I'm coding like this :

```
BOOL IsMaxButton=((GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE)&WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)==WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
BOOL IsMinButton=((GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE)&WS_MINIMIZEBOX)==WS_MINIMIZEBOX);
```

However, it doesn't work. When you use the spy to check the styles of some windows, no style bit was found, but the windows still have the max/min buttons.

Anybody can tell my why ? How does the window style works?

Comment: Not all windows have their non-client area controlled by the OS.

Comment: I'm using this to coding some windows. I'm not sure whats your point . I guess you mean the max/min buttons not painted according to the window styles, some extra change or modification have been applied to this unformal windows(which you said not controlled by the OS). Well, I'm coding, following the rule of the standard windows style, will the code above  work ?@IInspectable